# SharePoint Issues log

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

This is what I am trying to do:

- I need to use an issues log on my team's SharePoint site.
- I need a number of people to receive email notifications once an user makes a new entry into the log.
- The problem is, what I have learnt so far, the issues log can only notify one person or a group of people for every new entry, and what I need to do is that based on the type of entry in one of my columns of the log, only one person would receive the email.  For example, if the issue is about sales, then I want only "Mary" to be notified, and if the issue is about product defects, then I want only "Pete" to be notified.
- It doesn't seem like SharePoint will allow me to go to that level, unless you please let me know how.
- Then I thought as a work around I could create multiple issues logs (I will need about 11 for each type of issue), that way I make sure only the  people I want receives the notification.   The New problem with this is that the logs will be now isolated, and I need to have a consolidated report once a month.  Is it possible to have SharePoint automatically extract all the content into a master issues log?

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right track, and you can see with SharePoint there is more than a single way to solve a problem.  You did not define what version of SharePoint you are using, as that too can determine what avenues you can take to solve this issue, so I will throw out a few options for you.

---

Sticking with the multiple list / alerts.  With this approach you just need to assign the proper people up (or have them do it) to get the alerts from the list, so not much for you to change on this end.  For a Roll up, well that is where the answer gets tricky.

If you are using Foundation 2010, there are no default rollup web part, but you can use a Data View Web Part.  You will use a data connection to the list web services and pull the content in.

If you are using Server, you can leverage the "content query web part" or "Search Results Web Part" to rollup items from different lists.

If you are using 2013 foundation you can utilize the "Search Results Web Part'.

---

Another option, is to keep it all in a single list and create a simple workflow via SharePoint designer.  The workflow could be a single step, firing off an email to the person specified in a specific column (or based on a column) and then ending.

---

Some Additional resources to assist you:

SharePoint Designer Workflows
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx

Data View Web Part:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/web-parts-for-views-and-forms-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101805424.aspx

Using Calculated Column to aggregate list items:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/vlookup-type-rollup-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Thanks!   I created individual issues logs but I am still stuck with all the logs not being integrated unless i download and merge manually..oh well, I guess this is another one of sharepoint's limitations.     I am using Sharepoint server and unfortunately I son't have access to Designer.

Comment: With server you have access to the content query web part, did you try that?  This link is for 2007 but applicable to 2010 as well:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx